# Archive function missing from Outlook 2010 cleanup

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving

I'm trying to do a manual archive in **Outlook 2010** and internet instructions say to select `Cleanup > Cleanup Folder > Archive;` however there is no Archive function listed in the Cleanup Folder.

Also, when I right-click on an Outlook folder, select cleanup folder, settings, the icon under Conservation cleanup has an X next to it, indicating it is deselected (?)

Comment: It's worth checking to see if you can get to Archive in a different view. See this reference on the different ways you can Archive with different views http://www.addintools.com/documents/outlook/where-archive.html

Comment: @user1970450 - You should talk with your IT department because the `Archive` option should be there.  So the only possability it that it was perhaps disabled.  In the end you can duplicate this functionality by just creating a .pst, loading it into the profile, and moving the files by hand.

Comment: @Ramhound I would even suggest further that you backup the original .pst before creating/importing a new one - just to be safe.

Comment: @root - If somebody is using an Exchange server by default they don't have a .PST in most cases unless they are using the archive function or perhaps using an automatic backup mechanic of some kind.

Comment: Good point. We use this tool on some of our machines for specific backups, worth considering for some cases (even just as a reminder to backup) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9003

Answer (score -1):

if your server admin has set your exchange to auto archive you will no longer have access to the outlook auto archive.

If you right click any email & see Assign Policy your admin has removed your control of the archive function